# URL to open Access Web DB form at specific record

Tags: database, forms, ms-access, sharepoint, web

I would like to create an email workflow using an Access Web DB form to manage holiday requests. The user will create a request from the form, save it - which triggers the SendMail data macro, ideally with a link in it for the approver to click and go to the approval form filtered to the correct request ID.

Does anybody know:

a) If it is possible to load the form in the browser filtered at the specific record ID. I have tried appending ?ID=1 to the form URL and so on, without any joy so far.

```
    https://mysharepointserver.com/sites/mywebapp/default.aspx?ID=1
```

b) If possible, what steps do I need to go through to get it working?

This is an Access 2010 web database hosted on a heavily bespoke Sharepoint platform. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked it out, using:

```
    ?Page={ID}
```

However, the one caveat with this is that if you delete a record then the page number refers to the records position in the table, not specifically the ID. If you can ensure that records are never deleted from the table it will remain aligned with Page number and ID number.

Its a bit of a pain, but if anyone finds a way of referencing ID directly that would be the ideal solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use something along the lines of:

`http://...sp_site_path.../default.aspx#Type=Form&Path=NavForm.Subform&Name=ActualForm&DataMode=Edit&Where=%3DID%3D1000`

I believe the key part here is...

`&Where=%3DID%3D1000`

...which in this case refers to the database field [ID] and record 1000, ie:

`[ID]=1000`

The rest of the URL is refers to a specfic form within your site, however is you only have one, it is potentially not important for your purpose, and you would be able to get by with something like:

`http://...sp_site_path.../default.aspx#Where=%3DID%3D1000`

Since all my sites use navigation pages, I haven't tested this out